# problem in get value by ".serialize()"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want after click on `#value(VALUE)` get value `input:checkbox` with `.serialize()` ?

**EXAMPLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/tKBJ2/40/

```
$('#value').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    alert("this alert only after click on '#value'");
        $('.table_show tr').each(function(){
            if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                var dataString = $('.table_show').serialize(); // This don't work
                alert(dataString);                
                $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut("slow");
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://localhost/admin/customer_size/delete",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(){
                    },
                    error: function(data){
                        alert('Load was performed.');
                    }
                })                
            }
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`serialize()` is used to get query string from the inputs of a form, you should check if the selector select a form element or not.

cf jquery doc : http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Encapsulate your div `table`_show in a `form`, and do serialize on this `form`:

```
<form class="myForm">
  <div class="table_show">
    rest of your code
  </div>
</form>
```

Then in your js :

```
var dataString = $('.myForm').serialize();
```

Comment: not for me, if I click on value, I can see the form query string in the alert